# What's this black handle on my fireplace? It moves up and goes left

Tags: fireplace

[image]My fireplace is manufactured by arrowhead brass. Its a gas fireplace. There's a part to the left outside of the fireplace curtain and it's this iron black handle thing as seen in the picture. It moves up, then left and stays there.

Comment: Probably a damper. With any luck someone who knows your fireplace model will happen along and confirm or refute that. Or you could light some incense (or other small smoke source, it's usually the handiest in the "safe" line) and put it in the fireplace (fireplace unlit) to see if you can verify a change in smoke behavior consistent with it being a damper.

Comment: I don't think code allows dampers in gas fireplaces.

Comment: Must have at some point, as we had another question where someone had left it closed and run the gas fire. Of course, if there is one it **should** somehow be tied into the gas system so the fire can't be lit if it's closed, but....

Comment: My bet would be that it's meant to control the air intake damper. If you look around outside near the fireplace, you may see a vent near the side or bottom. though you may not, as this feature may not be connected. The fresh air intake is meant to allow outdoor air (or non-conditioned air) to be used for combustion, to prevent conditioned air from your home being used. Whether or not it's hooked up depends on the installation. I'm not familiar with your model, so I'm not sure which way is open/closed. You should check the owners manual, or contact the manufacturer.

Comment: This is not to be confused with the flue damper, which would be near the top of the firebox.

Answer (score 3):

I found this 5 year old unanswered question because I'm in search of a similar question for my own fireplace insert except that I'm looking for a rod.  I bet this is the damper control lever (yes, not the same damper as the one at the top center of the stove.  This damper should be in the in the flue- and I bet this little rod both moves and pulls out (pulls out to close the damper and moves to hold it closed).  I should add that the damper itself (the disk) will never completely close, it's missing approx 1/4 top of the circle where the joint is, probably for safety purposes so perhaps it is for gas as well.

These inserts are so old, mine is a 1970 Fisher Grandmother stove and boy is this a wild goose chase!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.